# Extra values from list inside a dictionary column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
label_dict
[{'colour': 'Red', 'value': '20'}, {'colour': 'Black', 'value': '23'}, {'colour': 'Brown ', 'value': '12'}, ]
[{'colour': 'Red', 'value': '15'}, {'colour': 'Black', 'value': '76'}, {'colour': 'Brown ', 'value': '45'}, ]
[{'colour': 'Black', 'value': '54'}, {'colour': 'Brown ', 'value': '56'}, ]
[{'colour': 'Brown ', 'value': '63'}, ]
.
.
.
[]
[{'colour': 'Red', 'value': '45'}, {'colour': 'Black', 'value': '48'}, {'colour': 'Brown ', 'value': '1'},
```

I want to extract the value if Red is present in the dictionary to column name `df[Red]`

```
df['Red'] = df['label_dict'].apply(lambda x: next((y.get('value', '') for y in x if y.get('colour') == 'Red'), ''))

df['Red'] = df['label_dict'].apply(lambda x: x.get('Red') if x else None)
```

Both ways gives me an error

Comment: What is `public_equities` and how is it related to the dictionary?

Comment: `label_dict` looks like a series of lists of dictionaries, not a series of dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar fixed typo

Comment: It's still the case that your column contains a list, not a dictionary. You need to loop over the list. You could use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pandas approach

Explode the label column then extract the value corresponding to Red colour then group the dataframe by index and select first value per group:

```
s = df['label_dict'].explode()
df['Red'] = s.str['value'].mask(s.str['colour'].ne('Red')).groupby(level=0).first()
```

Result:

```
>>> df['Red']                                                                                                

0      20
1      15
2    None
3    None
Name: Red, dtype: object
```